# How is type resolution done?

Tags: java, types, casting, polymorphism, substitution

I'm new to the Java world and I have some problems figuring out how Java decides which method to call when there is polymorphism. Can you help me figure out how it works with this example?
I tried the code and saw the results. I am more interested in why does it work this way.

```
class A {
    void redef(A a) { System.out.println("[A]"); }
}

class B extends A {
    //@Override
    void redef(B b) { System.out.println("[B]"); }
}

class C extends B {
}

public class Surcharge {
    static void surcharge(A a) { System.out.println("[A]"); }
    static void surcharge(B b) { System.out.println("[B]"); }

    public static void main(String[] argv) {

        A a = new A() ;
        B b = new B() ;

        A ab = new B();
        C c = new C();

        ab.redef(c); //?
        surcharge(a); //?
        surcharge(b); //?
        surcharge(c); //?
        surcharge(ab); //?
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you narrow your question down to the behavior here that doesn't make sense to you? as it stands this is too much like, "Here, do my homework for me".

Comment: Additionally, you may want to give the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) a read. You should always include [what you've tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) along with any research you've done in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a method is overloaded (like all your methods here), Java uses the method which matches the most closely with the declared type of the argument.

In the first example, the object (`ab`) being of declared type A, the compiler only knows about the method `redef(A a)`, so it's chosen.

Note that the method `redef(B)` does NOT override the method `redef(A)`, since its signature doesn't match. You would have a compile error if you uncommented the `@Override` annotation.

In the second example, only `sucharge(A a)` matches with the declared type of the argument (A), so this one is chosen.

In the third example, `surcharge(B b)` matches the declared type of the argument (B) more closely, so it's chosen.

Same for the fourth example.

In the last example, only `surcharge(A a)` applies to the declared type of the argument (A), so it's chosen.